# How do you unlink shared memory segments if the process unexpectedly dies?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I need shared memory in my program, but if the process were to unexpectedly die, the shared memory segments would still exist and cause a seg fault every time I launch the program. Is there a way to make sure shared memory is unlinked upon process termination without having to explicitly call `unlink`? I heard that System V can do this with `shmctl`, but is there a way to do it with POSIX?

For example, if I'm on Linux and have the code:

```
char** global_msg;
int shm_fd1 = shm_open("GLOBAL_MSG", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
ftruncate(shm_fd, MAX_MSG_LEN);
global_msg = (char **) mmap(NULL, MAX_MSG_LEN, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

*global_msg = 0;
```

how would I make sure that "GLOBAL_MSG" is unlinked if the process unexpectedly dies?

Comment: if the process dies  unexpectedly , not too much we can guarantee.   how about actively detect  the shared memory status every time you launch the program?

Comment: @bigdataolddriver how would I do that?

Comment: current working code prefered , and alone with your expected OS  version info , not only ```POSIX```

Comment: I am not sure if there are some in-built flags for that. But you can do it in a signal handler and I guess functions required for the purpose can be safely called in the handler aswell.

Comment: Why would an existing shared memory segment cause a seg fault? You're checking for errors and handling appropriately in your real code, right?

Comment: Also `GLOBAL_MSG` is not a valid shared memory identifier as it's lacking a leading slash.

Comment: Agree with @Mihir . You can specify a handler function for that. There can be function that can be called if facing seg fault, and write shmctl and pass shared memory ID with that to remove the shared memory. We do it basically as a cleanup activity so as to make sure the next time the program start it does not throw error while creating/accessing shared memory with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
char** global_msg;
int shm_fd = shm_open("GLOBAL_MSG", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
ftruncate(shm_fd, MAX_MSG_LEN);
global_msg = (char **) mmap(NULL, MAX_MSG_LEN, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
shm_unlink("GLOBAL_MSG")
*global_msg = 0;
```

Just like POSIX allows you to delete a file while it's open, and still work with the content, and the file is only really gone once it's closed by all programs, so does shared memory.

[Quote](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shm_unlink.html):

> If one or more references to the shared memory object exist when the object is unlinked, the name shall be removed before shm_unlink() returns, but the removal of the memory object contents shall be postponed until all open and map references to the shared memory object have been removed.

Comment: I suppose that works, but it kind of defeats the purpose.  Presumably the whole reason for using a shared memory segment is so that unrelated processes can open it by name.

Comment: Fair enough, but if the other process is unrelated, then (1) shared memory is not the right tool for the job and (2) How would you know when to unlink the shared memory?
If the other process is related, then both processes could open the memory, and then unlink can be done.